# Safari Javascript error with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, safari, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting this error when I load my page in Safari:

> TypeError: Result of expression
>   'map.getCenter' [undefined] is not a
>   function.

The same page loads absolutely fine in every other major browser (Chrome, FF, and IE).

I'm using Google Maps Javascript API V3 along with their Geolocation API.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Here's the code path:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        initialize();
    });


function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
         saveSession();
        });
        getInitialLocation();
    }

function getInitialLocation()
    {
        // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);

            }, function () {
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Try Google Gears Geolocation
        } else if (google.gears) {

            browserSupportFlag = true;

            var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
            geo.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            }, function () {
                handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        } else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (!errorFlag)
            {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(geoip_latitude(), geoip_longitude());
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            }
        }
    }
```

You see the `idle` is bound to `saveSession()`

```
function saveSession() {
        if ((map != undefined) && (map.getCenter() != undefined)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

But this should only run the code if that stuff ISN'T undefined. Also, once again, this WORKS in everything but Safari.

EDIT: Run this in JFiddle WITH safari. It will come up and work after about 5 seconds. But then run it again (either update or hit run again). It will not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/gYJrF/1/

Comment: How do you load the map? Can you show a code example?

Comment: any chance for a live example ? or at least some source code so we can see what is going on ..

Comment: I load the map the way they recommend, here; http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried switching these two lines of code

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
     saveSession();
    });
    getInitialLocation();
```

to

```
    getInitialLocation();
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
     saveSession();
    });
```

in case safari fires the `idle` event before having set the center of the map.

---

*or even better if you could bind to the `idle` event after certainly having set the map center. So maybe set it inside the `getInitialLocation` in the success callbacks and for the failed in the `handleNoGeolocation`*

---

It seems that it is a wide-spread issue with Safari.

- https://discussions.apple.com/message/11780026?messageID=11780026
- http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=318586.0

I am assuming it is a desktop-only problem, as from posts i see that devices with GPS will work with (*iphone etc*)

Comment: I have not. But I will. Good idea

Comment: Still is not working. I am binding to idle right after the line of code map.setCenter(); and it's still complaining

Comment: Added in jfiddle. follow the instructions though. works first time (after taking long), doesn't work second time - ONLY in safari. works everywhere else

Comment: @slandau, updated answer at the end (*seems that it is an issue with the safari implementation, and it is wide-spread*)

Comment: But the thing is it does work, just not the first time. I think it's trying saveSession() twice on page re-load.

Comment: @slandau, on my PC (win 7 64bit), safari (v5.0.5) cannot geolocate at all.. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` always runs the fail callback, although it supports the `navigator.geolocation` API. Even the official google tutorials say that geolocation failed. I am out of ideas on this one..

Comment: @slandau, in addition to the above message, i need to let you know that i never get the error you mention.. What OS and Safari do you use ? (*versions included*)

Comment: I am using Safari 5 with Windows XP Pro. So what your saying is, it will never go into google gears, or the next failsafe, because it technically "supports" geolocation it just doesn't work?

Comment: @slandau, that is what i *experience* from the tests.. i hope someone knows of a workaround..

Comment: Hmm, so if I'm understanding this right, it's not working because when it goes into the handleNoGelocation, it's setting the flag as if it worked, when it really didn't. Okay...I'll look into this. thank you

Comment: @slandau,maybe checking the browser and forcibly using gears if it is safari would help .. (*although i dislike the concept, i cannot think of an alternative if a browser has a possible bug*)

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm going to try and do. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @slandau, no problem . Let me/us know if you manage to make it work .. It will be very helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is telling you that it doesn't know what `map.getCenter` is. It probably means that `map` wasn't initialized, was deleted, or is not available in whatever function is generating the error. Try setting a breakpoint and look backwards through the stack trace to see where things have gone wrong.

You can reproduce the error with something like this:

```
<script>
function init() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map( /* params */ );
}

function get_map_center() {
    return map.getCenter();  // map is not defined here, it was only defined
                             // in the init() function above. 
}
</script>

...

<body onload="init">
...
</body>
```